# Rails enumerize with dynamic options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, dynamic, enums

I have a model to handle different application settings. Each setting has a value_type e.g. string, integer, boolean and enum. If a settings is defined as enum, it has many enum_options (just saved as key, value with a reference to the setting in database).
To handle these enums I want to use [Enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) gem. I tried a lot but I can't set enum option from database.

Here is my code how I try to define the different enum options.

```
enumerize :enum_values, in: -> { EnumOption.where(functional_parameter_id: self.id).map(&:value.to_sym) }
```

After that I try to call `Setting.find(1).enum_values` and I got `nil`.

If I call `Setting.enum_values.values` to get all available options to select, I just got `["#<Proc:0x007fd7e78e9218@/Users/path/to/app/app/models/setting.rb:31 (lambda)>"]`

Is it possible to set the enum options dynamically?

Comment: Which version of Rails and Ruby are you using? And where do you have this code? inside `Setting ` class?

Comment: Rails version 4.1.5, `enumerize :enum_vlaues...` in Setting model. `Setting.find`and `Setting.enum_values`called from rails console

Comment: actually from gem's doc, it seems you need to provide a default value(in case there's no value selected/saved before), did you set any default value to `enum_vlaues` after adding this gem in your app? if not then shouldn't it be nil as you got in `Setting.find(1).enum_values`?

Comment: Now i set a default but enum_values are stil nil. `enumerize :enum_values, in: -> { EnumOption.where(setting_id: self.id).map(&:value.to_sym) }, default: lambda { |param| EnumOption.where(setting_is: param.id).first.value.to_sym }`

Comment: No, my point is, you need to save some data first in database before accessing it. Try: `s = Setting.find(1); s.update_attributes(:enum_values => EnumOption.where(functional_parameter_id: s.id).first(2)` and then try your other query you've posted in question: `Setting.find(1).enum_values` and see if it's still nil in your rails console.

Comment: There are some demo date in the database available

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `in` with a lamdba literal in enumerize. This feature is not documented anywhere, and having a look at https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize/blob/c65867580967724479af1bffbfbea05cbfa62db4/lib/enumerize/attribute.rb#L15, it seems that enumerize strictly wants you to pass an array.